# How can I make gvim keyboard language-agnostic in command mode?

Tags: gvim, keyboard-layout, x11

Sometimes I'm using GVim not only for coding, but also for typing texts in Russian language.

I'm very annoyed that I have to switch my keyboard layout back to English each time when I return to command mode. Is there any way to make GVim obeying keycodes sent by X server rather than keysyms, so that it could work in command mode regardless to which keyboard layout is selected?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the plugins `https://github.com/lyokha/vim-xkbswitch` or `https://github.com/rlue/vim-barbaric`, which switch the input method in vim's input mode using xkbswitch.